# Shift time in multi-index to merge

Tags: python, pandas, merge, multi-index, datetimeindex

I want to merge two datasets that are indexed by `time` and `id`. The problem is, the time is slightly different in each dataset. In one dataset, the time (Monthly) is mid-month, so the 15th of every month. In the other dataset, it is the last business day. This should still be a one-to-one match, but the dates are not exactly the same.

My approach is to shift mid-month dates to business day end-of-month dates.

Data:

```
dt = pd.date_range('1/1/2011','12/31/2011', freq='D')
dt = dt[dt.day == 15]
lst = [1,2,3]
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dt,lst],names=['date','id'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(idx)), index=idx)
df.head()
```

output:

```
                      0
date       id
2011-01-15 1  -0.598584
           2  -0.484455
           3  -2.044912
2011-02-15 1  -0.017512
           2   0.852843
```

This is what I want (I removed the performance warning):

```
In[83]:df.index.levels[0] + BMonthEnd()
Out[83]:
DatetimeIndex(['2011-01-31', '2011-02-28', '2011-03-31', '2011-04-29',
               '2011-05-31', '2011-06-30', '2011-07-29', '2011-08-31',
               '2011-09-30', '2011-10-31', '2011-11-30', '2011-12-30'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='BM')
```

However, indexes are immutable, so this does not work:

```
In: df.index.levels[0] = df.index.levels[0] + BMonthEnd()

TypeError: 'FrozenList' does not support mutable operations.
```

The only solution I've got is to reset_index(), change the dates, then set_index() again:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df['date'] = df['date'] + BMonthEnd()
df.set_index(['date','id'], inplace=True)
```

This gives what I want, but is this the best way? Is there a set_level_values() function (I didn't see it in the API)?

Or maybe I'm taking the wrong approach to the merge. I could merge the dataset with keys `df.index.get_level_values(0).year`, `df.index.get_level_values(0).month` and `id` but this doesn't seem much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to merge anyway, you can forget about changing the index and use use `pandas.merge_asof()`

## Data

`df1`

```
                      0
date       id          
2011-01-15 1  -0.810581
           2   1.177235
           3   0.083883
2011-02-15 1   1.217419
           2  -0.970804
           3   1.262364
2011-03-15 1  -0.026136
           2  -0.036250
           3  -1.103929
2011-04-15 1  -1.303298
```

And here is one with last business day of the month,  `df2`

```
                      0
date       id          
2011-01-31 1  -0.277675
           2   0.086539
           3   1.441449
2011-02-28 1   1.330212
           2  -0.028398
           3  -0.114297
2011-03-31 1  -0.031264
           2  -0.787093
           3  -0.133088
2011-04-29 1   0.938732
```

## merge

Use `df1` as your left `DataFrame` and then choose the merge direction as forward since the last business day is always after the 15th. Optionally, you can set a tolerance. This is useful in the situation where you are missing a month in the right `DataFrame` and will prevent you from merging `03-31-2011` to `02-15-2011` if you are missing data for the last business day February.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.merge_asof(df1.reset_index(), df2.reset_index(), by='id', on='date', 
              direction='forward', tolerance=pd.Timedelta(days=20)).set_index(['date', 'id'])
```

Results in

```
                    0_x       0_y
date       id                    
2011-01-15 1  -0.810581 -0.277675
           2   1.177235  0.086539
           3   0.083883  1.441449
2011-02-15 1   1.217419  1.330212
           2  -0.970804 -0.028398
           3   1.262364 -0.114297
2011-03-15 1  -0.026136 -0.031264
           2  -0.036250 -0.787093
           3  -1.103929 -0.133088
2011-04-15 1  -1.303298  0.938732
```

Comment: This is excellent - on my larger data, this merge is faster than re-setting the index and then merging.

Comment: Also, I wanted to keep the month end dates, so I just changed `direction='backward'` and the order of the data frames and that works.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`set_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.set_levels.html) in order to set multiindex levels:

```
df.index.set_levels(df.index.levels[0] + pd.tseries.offsets.BMonthEnd(),
                    level='date', inplace=True)


>>> df.head()
                      0
date       id          
2011-01-31 1  -1.410646
           2   0.642618
           3  -0.537930
2011-02-28 1  -0.418943
           2   0.983186
```

Comment: I'm out of votes, but I cleared one out and upvoted this because I like this solution as well.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated! I liked your solution as well!

Comment: This is an excellent, clean solution to the problem of re-indexing, but I marked the solution below as the answer because it solved my overall problem of merging with better performance. By skipping the re-indexing, it was faster overall.

Answer (score 5):

You could just build it again:

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
    [
       df.index.get_level_values(0) + BMonthEnd(),
       df.index.get_level_values(1)
])
```

`set_levels` implicitly rebuilds the index under the covers. If you have more than two levels, this solution becomes unweildy, so consider using `set_levels` for typing brevity.

Comment: This works as well. I hadn't thought of this approach.